# How to prevent apps on one iPad from being loaded automatically on the other?

Tags: ios

Could you please tell me how I can keep whatever apps I download to one of my iPads from downloading to the other iPad? Thank you very much for your help. NOTE: I am disabled, so the easiest answer, the better. Again, thank you.

- iPad 1, 64 GB, WiFi-only
- iPad 2, 64 GB, 3G and WiFi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your iPad device tap on **Settings** > **Store**. Under where it says **Automatic Downloads**, make sure that **Apps** is set to **Off**. This setting keeps apps from automatically downloading new purchases made on other devices.

Comment: It's that easy? Wow! No connecting to a computer? Thank you so much, Bryan.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your iPad to your computer, go to iTunes, select your iPad in the column on the left side. Click apps in the top bar, and deselect "synchronize apps". Do that for every iPad.